# Where do you charge your batteries?

Tags: hardware

I'm travelling to shoot a documentary in a remote pacific island without any electricity.

How do you charge your batteries in such conditions ? I have never used a generator and I'm afraid of the noise level. So I was wondering if there is a better solutions for such shooting conditions.

Thanks

Comment: What type and size battery? How many? How quickly do you need them recharged?

Comment: Whatever batteries you are in need of charging (travel with as many spares as you can afford), you are going to have to use the generator(s). Why? There's not other option, as there's no electricity. The situation is not ideal, but it's what it is. As for generators, usually people don't set them up right under their windows, but a bit away and even sometimes in small hut-like structures. So don't worry about the noise.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no electricity and you're not keen on using a generator, this is your solution: [a DIY battery solar charger](https://nofilmschool.com/2016/11/how-to-build-cheap-solar-camera-charger-for-adventure-filmmaking)